# facebook post photo on the friends wall with android sdk

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.x

I am a new developer on Android. I am trying to make an app that people can manupulate the image then share it on facebook or other social networks. I have downloaded the facebook sdk 4.9 then followed the all instructions. The problem is that, I can share my links and photos via facebook share button or share dialog (actually facebook share button triggers to share dialog anyway). For both solutions, I can only post photos on my facebook wall then just select the privacy statements.

I know it is a simple question for many of you, but if you help me to solve that problem, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to post anything on the wall of friends. You can only post on your own wall - with the `/me/photos` endpoint, for example.

Possibilities for Sharing on Android are explained in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. I just wanted to make my question clear. I know, we can not share a photo directly to our friend's wall, but when we try to send it via intent we can choose whether to share on our wall or friends wall. Is there any possible way to show share dialog that contains share option like we have in share via intent?